How can I tell which furnace blower capacitor is faulty?
Yesterday I had licenced technician performing thorough inspection.
There are 2 parts needing replacement:

Whl 0247 blower wheel
5mfd 370v blower capacitor.

The blower wheel is dirty and rusty. What is the easiest way I can get it out?
I think there are 2 motor capacitors. One is by the blower wheel. The other is outside somewhere in AC unit.
I'm not sure which one is the bad one. Are they both called the same thing?
I'm adding photos.
my AC
My furnace
My inspection papers

We do not do costs.  You need to check local city/town/county/state regulations on what you can buy/do.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Also have a look at the [help]. We don't do cost questions here, and whether you can do something is none of our business. Also, ask just one question per post, and provide enough detail for us to help. We have no idea how your blower comes out because you haven't told us a thing about your hardware. Help us help you.

Capacitors are labeled.   Clean them and take a close look.

Photos added as 3 links

Images can and should be added directly to your question, using the "mountains" icon in the edit box. (I wish they'd change that to a camera icon.)

I understand I need new capacitor. It costs $2 -15 so it's a nonbrainer. Does it mater which brand I buy? As long as it says the same model name I should be fine, right? What about blower wheel? I'm assuming it is just blower wheel and not blower wheel motor. Should I replace this wheel based on my photos or can I just clean it with wire brush and leave it?

Capacitors are technically not electrically connected from one side to the other since they are two conductors separated by a dielectric. They are an open electrically if they are still good. Bad ones usually dead short.
If you only have an ohmmeter without a capacitance test then the capicitor should be discharged first by shorting the leads together.
After that, if you test for Ohms across the capacitor, at first, instantly, it will read zero (dead short) and then as as the capacitor charges, the ohmic value will climb to infinity. If you reverse the leads the process will repeat in the opposite direction. This indicates a good capacitor since as it charges it is now an electrical open with effectively infinite resistance.
If you get zero resistance or very low value repeatedly after reversing polarity several times, without the charge up to infinity, then the capacitor is broke or at the very least suspect.
Many "broken" capacitors will "puff up like a toad" and be distorted from their normal dimensions and are visually suspect of being damaged. Especially AC capacitors for motors. The normal fail mode for a capacitor is to dead short which is the opposite of their normal operating mode.
Good luck!
